# Array to string conversion email unique validation Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

Hi there can someone please help me, I have to make my email unique I tried this way.

```
    public function sendform(MenteesFormRequest $request){
 $email = $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'email',
            Rule::unique('users'),
    ]]);



        $mentees = User::create([
            'first_name' => $request['first_name'],
            'last_name'  => $request['last_name'],
            'email'      => $email,
            'user_group'       => 3,
             'remember_token'   => str_random(40)
        ]);


         return redirect()->back();

    }
```

It shows the validation good but when   I try to submit this it gives me this error :

```
"Array to string conversion"
```

Comment: Your request info is in `$request->first_name` or `$request->input('first_name')` I don't know if this is your issue though. Are you sure the validation is failing and not the `User::create()` call?

Answer (score 0):

Because your $email is array, to do this:

```
$mentees = User::create([
        'first_name' => $request['first_name'],
        'last_name'  => $request['last_name'],
        'email'      => $request['email'],
        'user_group'       => 3,
         'remember_token'   => str_random(40)
    ]);
```